# Having trouble getting values of dynamically generated input (jQuery and Mustache)

Tags: jquery, mustache

I'm trying to store the values of input into an object, however those inputs are generated dynamically with Mustache. I am allowing the user to add a "treatment period" and for each period I want to get data such as start date, end date, symptoms (for symptoms I am also allowing the users to add more than one by clicking on a button), etc.  When I try to loop over the dynamically created treatment period divs and store all the data associated with one period in a variable with the .each() method I am not able to retrieve the values of the input fields that were associated with a dynamically generated ID.

Below is the Mustache template (the submit button is not part of it since it is static, so I didn't include it but it's just a div with the id submit):

```
      <div class="treatment-wrapper">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label for="start-treatment{{count}}">Start Date</label>
                            <input type="text" id="start-treatment{{count}}" name="start-treatment{{count}}" required placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <label for="end-treatment{{count}}">End Date</label>
                            <input type="text" id="end-treatment{{count}}" name="end-treatment{{count}}" required placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <label for="symptom{{count}}">Symptoms </label>
                            <div id="symptom{{count}}-results" class="symptom-results">
                            </div>
                            <div class="field2">
                                <input type="text" class="symptom" id="symptom{{count}}" name="symptom{{count}}" required>
                                <div class="button add-symptom" id="add-symptom-{{count}}">ADD</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

     </div><!-- end treatment-wrapper -->
```

And here is the JS and jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click','#submit',function(e){

                     //for each treatment period, get every input stored
                     var treatment_pd_info = {
                        "start_date":'',
                        "end_date":'',
                        "symptoms":[]
                     };


                     $('.treatment-wrapper').each(function(i){

                        var start_date = $("#start-treatment"+(i+1)).val();
                        var end_date = $("#end-treatment"+(i+1)).val();

                        console.log('start_date');
                        console.log(start_date);

                        var symptoms = $('#symptom'+(i+1)+'-results').find(".symptom-button").val();

                        console.log('symptoms');
                        console.log(symptoms);


                            $('#symptom'+(i+1)+'-results .symptom-results').each(function(index){
                                    console.log(index);

                             });

                     });

             });
```

for the above code, with I do a console.log, start_date is blank, symptoms is undefined, and index doesn't show up.  Could someone maybe point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use the browser's inspect feature to look at the HTML being generated.  My guess is that count is undefined in the object/template.

Comment: actually it seems to be appearing, for example I see <label for = "start-treatment1"> Start Date </label> <input type = "text" id="start-treatment1" name = "start-treatment1" required placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">

Comment: I would recommend to get the #start-treatment and other components relative to the current ".treatment-wrapper" being evaluated. You can do that by $(this).child(".start-treatment"). ANd you assign "start-treatment" class to the input element

Comment: plus, you need to show us the code which renders that Mustache template. It should have a function like var count = 0; mustacheData['count'] = function(){ return ++count;}

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches - One is to assign a counter to the elements and then another is to fetch elements relatively.

```
var count = 0;
function loadMustacheTemplate(){
  var mustacheData = {}; 
  mustacheData['count'] = function(){ return ++count; }
  var html = Mustache.toHtml($("#mytemplate").html(), mustacheData);
  $("#my-container").html(html);
}
```

Approach 2:

```
<input type="text" class="start-treatment" 
    id="start-treatment{{count}}" 
    name="start-treatment{{count}}" required 
    placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
```

Assign a new class to the inputs as shown above:

```
$('.treatment-wrapper').each(function(i){
  var startTreatment = $(this).child(".start-treatment").val();
});
```

Do the above for all other elements.